# Assign variable in sql query select

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

```
Declare @cardNumber;
select name, address, 
 (select @cardNumber = select top 1 value from card cd
         inner join cardNotuse cdnu on cd.id = cdnu.cardId
         where cdnu.type = 'CreditCard'),
case when (@cardNumber = 1) then 'TopPriority'
     when (@cardNumber = 2) then 'SecondPriority'
     Else 'Normal' end as PriorityLeval

from customer
```

I can't assign value to `@cardNumber` by somehow. Error I've got is

> 'Incorrect syntax near '='.

I couldn't figure out why I couldn't use the query like that.

Comment: Also, it is not permitted in sql server to return result from a select query as well as assign some value in a variable in same query.

Comment: Even fixing the syntax I doubt the query does what you want.   Every single  @cardNumber is the same.

Answer (score 1):

As variable @cardNumber is not related to customer table you can write two independent queries AS:

```
Declare @cardNumber int;
set @cardNumber =  (SELECT  top 1 value 
                       from card cd
                       inner join cardNotuse cdnu on cd.id = cdnu.cardId
                       where cdnu.[type] = 'CreditCard')
select  name,
        address, 
        @cardNumber,
        case when (@cardNumber = 1) then 'TopPriority'
             when (@cardNumber = 2) then 'SecondPriority'
             Else 'Normal' end as PriorityLeval
from customer
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the sample and comment.

```
Declare @cardNumber varchar(50) --here datatype missing

select name, address, 
        (--select @cardNumber =  --you can not do 2 thing in one select query, either set variable or get result, not both in a single query
        select top 1 value from card cd
         inner join cardNotuse cdnu on cd.id = cdnu.cardId
         where cdnu.type = 'CreditCard'
         ),
case when (@cardNumber = 1) then 'TopPriority'
     when (@cardNumber = 2) then 'SecondPriority'
     Else 'Normal' end as PriorityLeval

from customer 

--1. Either set statment to get value 
set @cardNumber =  
        (select top 1 value from card cd
         inner join cardNotuse cdnu on cd.id = cdnu.cardId
         where cdnu.type = 'CreditCard'
         )
--2.  or in select query you can set,but result always be a single value as you taken top 1 will not work for you.
select @cardNumber = --this gives error as top clause will not work
        top 1 value from card cd
         inner join cardNotuse cdnu on cd.id = cdnu.cardId
         where cdnu.type = 'CreditCard'

--This will work. If a single value there, it return a value. If more than one value, set last record.
select @cardNumber = value _Id from card cd
             inner join cardNotuse cdnu on cd.id = cdnu.cardId
             where cdnu.type = 'CreditCard'
```

Comment: `select @cardNumber = 
        top 1 value from card cd` invalid SQL Server statement. `select top 1 @cardNumber = 
        value from card cd`